# Strange behaviour - instantiating a UITextField in willMoveToSuperview as opposed to didMoveToSuperview

Tags: ios, swift, oop, uiview, uitextfield

I'm working with XCode 6.3/iOS/Swift 1.2. I've just stumbled upon some strange behaviour that I don't understand (coming from a strong OO background).

Put simply, if I subclass a UIView and use it to instantiate some UITextFields; in the constructor, overriding didMoveToSuperview, on dynamically (ie, with a click event)... the UITextFields work as expected.  However, when creating the UITextField object during willMoveToSuperview, it *seems* fine... but it doesn't respond to touch events.

This is demonstrated in the code below (a UIViewController and the subclassed UIView).  I've added a gesture recognizer to the entire view containing the UITextFields.  Clicking any of them other than the one creating during willMoveToSuperview, will move the focus to that textfield, and will ignore the touch event (as expected).  However, clicking on the one added during willMoveToSuperview fires a touch event.  Event without the touch event... this textfield remains unresponsive.  Can anyone explain this behaviour?

```
import UIKit

class RootViewController:UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,500,500)

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        var uiview = ExtendedUIView()
        view.addSubview(uiview)
    }
}

class ExtendedUIView:UIView
{
    internal var hasMovedToSuperView:Bool = false

    override init (frame : CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame : frame)
    }

    convenience init()
    {
        self.init(frame:CGRectMake(0,0,500,500))

        var tf: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: 300, height: 40))
        tf.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        tf.text = "init // ok"
        addSubview(tf)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError("This class does not support NSCoding")
    }

    override func willMoveToSuperview(newSuperview: UIView?)
    {
        if (!hasMovedToSuperView) {

            var tf: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 300, height: 40))
            tf.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            tf.text = "willMoveToSuperview // not ok"
            addSubview(tf)    
        }
    }

    override func didMoveToSuperview()
    {
        if (!hasMovedToSuperView) {

            var tf: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 150, width: 300, height: 40))
            tf.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            tf.text = "didMoveToSuperview // ok"
            addSubview(tf)

            hasMovedToSuperView = true

            addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:Selector("createTFDynamically:")))
        }
    }

    func createTFDynamically(value:AnyObject)
    {
        var tf: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: 300, height: 40))
        tf.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        tf.text = "createTFDynamically // ok"
        addSubview(tf)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to point out: unless you have a reason to do otherwise, you should be adding views in `UIViewController` inside `viewDidLoad()` method, and adding views to custom view inside `init()` method.

Comment: @JakubVano - I have a reason to do otherwise